# How do I get the list of all the classes and methods used in a Java project in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been trying to list all the classes and methods in a java project in eclipse. I tried to create javadoc but it gave me some error. It wasn't created.

Is there any shortcut so that I can easily get the list of all the classes and methods or at least the list classes used in the project.

Comment: Windows search "*.class" files in bin folder shall do the job

Comment: @Sanjeev Thanks! I got the class list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try javap with no options, it may help you.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javap.html

Comment: It is helpful for getting the methods in a class not of the whole project. My project contains 4 different directories.

Comment: Try shortcut f4, or in Package Explorer, right click on the package in question, select Open Type Hierarchy.